# Error running an old project - Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, delphi

I am using object pascal in lazarus. When I open an old project and attempt to run it; this code window pops up in the source editor:

```
program TimeKeeper;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Interfaces, // this includes the LCL widgetset
  Forms, datetimectrls, TimeKeeperU1;

{$R *.res}

begin
  RequireDerivedFormResource := True;
  Application.Initialize;
        Application.CreateForm(TfrmTimeKeeper, frmTimeKeeper);

  Application.Run;
end.
```

This code window popup in the source window errors, is paired with these errors:

> TimeKeeper.lpr(20,1) Error: Can't create object file: TimeKeeper.exe
>   (error code: 5) TimeKeeper.lpr(20,1) Error: Can't create executable
>   TimeKeeper.exe

Does anyone know what the workaround is?

Comment: [ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx#ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) it pays to get to know a few of the more common Win32 error codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message indicates that the object file can't be created, which results in the application not being created. The error code 5 means *access denied*, which means you don't have write access to the directory where the compiler and linker are attempting to store output, or the executable is in use and can't be replaced (perhaps by anti-virus software), or it's been made read-only.

If the problem is with rights, the solutionis to either get sufficient rights to the directory or to change the output path of the project to a directory where you do have sufficient rights. This is typically done in *Project->Options* from the main menu.

If it's due to anti-virus software or another process that's using the executable, disable the AV software or provide an exception rule that prevents scanning that folder.

If the issue is caused by the file being read-only, change the file attributes to remove that attribute.

Comment: Thanks Ken. After I read your answer. The first thing I tried was deleting the old existing EXE file. This seems to have solved the problem as the program is running now from the IDE.

Comment: @CliffCrerar It is also may be caused by antivirus software which is prevents the creating of the executable by another executable for example.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be caused simply by having an executable of the program already running such as in an external terminal which is hidden from view. The compiler will not attempt to overwrite an .exe file that is open. Ask me how I know. :)